# Dropdown Menu overlaps with its container when content is large

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I' am using Bootstrap 3 to make [Dropdowns](http://jsfiddle.net/WLwEC/5/) of the menu upwards. Below is the screenshot off what I have currently and what is should be.

**Explanation**
So when a users clicks on the **Integrated transport solutions**, Dropdown menu opens upwards as you can see below in the images, this part is working fine. But when theirs large content the dropdown expands and overlaps with its container. I think something is wrong with my CSS. I' am still trying to figure it out.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
    <h3 class="heading">Over 100 years of commitment Over 100 years of commitment</h3>
    <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut et risus ut risus porttitor.</div>
    <div class="readmore"><a href="#">READ MORE <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></div>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="drop1" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Integrated transport solutions</a>
```

CSS

```
#home-carousel .caption .row .col-xs-6 ul.dropdown-menu{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -313px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    background: #FFF url(http://s30.postimg.org/jdtl0qyn1/caption_shadow.jpg) bottom center repeat-x;
    border-top: 5px solid #223c82;
    padding: 30px 15px 30px 15px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#home-carousel .caption .row .col-xs-6 a.dropdown-toggle{
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.caption .row .dropdown-menu h3{
    color: #223c82;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c264;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.caption .row .dropdown-menu .body{
    color: #223c82;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 21px;
}

.caption .row .dropdown-menu .readmore{
    padding-top: 23px;
    text-align: right;
}

.caption .row .dropdown-menu .readmore a{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #223c82;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#home-carousel .caption .row .col-xs-6 {
    background: url(http://s24.postimg.org/e18dg0mbp/mediabox_cover.png) repeat top;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 5px solid #c6c264;
    width: 208px;
    margin-right: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 5px 5px 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-left:100px;
}

#home-carousel .caption .row .col-xs-6 a.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I also assuming that the problem lays somewhere in **#home-carousel .caption .row .col-xs-6 ul.dropdown-menu** CSS. Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WLwEC/5/)

**Currently what I have**
[image]

**What it should be**
[image]

Comment: not sure if this is part of your question but in your html you have "Over 100 years of commitment" twice

Comment: No, thats just a dummy text am using currently.

Comment: maybe it's a good idea to turn you height:100% to min-height:100%; so it allows container to grow. (top:0; bottom:0; <= to check if useful or not :) )

Comment: h3 & div in ul should be wrapped in li by the way

Comment: @GCyrillus you are correct, please post as a answer. thanks!